# Dynamics AX Testdata Tansfer Tool with DB Cluster

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm trying to export data from a Dynamics AX 2012 R2 production environment using the [Test Data Transfer Tool](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/test-data-transfer-tool-beta-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/).
The problem is, that when I run the export command

```
dp.exe EXPORT C:\TDTT20170329 Live2012R2 my-cluster/GM2
```

I get following error message:

```
A connection with the  Server=my-cluster/GM2 cannot be established. Please check the Server is accessible

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
```

The AX DB is hosted on a SQL cluster configuration where **my-cluster** is the cluster. The cluster has two server nodes: **node-a** and **node-b**.

my-cluster
  |_node-a
  |_node-b

The AX database **Live2012R2** is running on node-a. However when we refer to the AX DB (for example from the Management Reporter) we user **my-cluster\GM2** to address the server instance.

I have tried to execute the above dp.exe EXPORT command on node-a and on node-b using different variations for the last parameter

- my-cluster/GM2 (executed on node a and node b)
- node-a/GM2 (executed on node a)
- node-b/GM2 (executed on node b)
- IP-Address/GM2 (executed on node a and node b)

The error messages stays the same (except for the server name, which mirrors the last parameter).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try it using a backslash instead of a forward slash?

Comment: yes - no result